# Ajax send model to controller as JSON

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a model I am trying to pass in from my view to my controller via an Ajax call which stringifies both the model and another string of data like this:

```
SetBinConfig: function (model, range) {
    var _model = JSON.stringify(model);
    var rangeSplit = range.split(/[ -]+/);
    var _rangeSplit = JSON.stringify(rangeSplit);

    var data = "model=" +_model + "&rangeSplit=" + _rangeSplit;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/IdentifiConfig/DefaultConfiguration/SetBinConfiguration',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "{'data' : '" + data + "'}",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.error == 1) {
                cc.jqUtils.openDialog(data.ErrorDescription, 'Error', 'OK', null, null, null);
            }
        },
        error: function (x, h, r) {
            console.log(x, h, r);
        }
    });
},
```

Which is then received by this method:

```
public ActionResult SetBinConfiguration(string data)
{
        string range = data.Split(new string[] { "&rangeSplit=" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
        string tempModelData = data.Split(new string[] {"&rangeSplit="}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
        string modelData = tempModelData.Replace("model=", "");

        DefaultConfigurationModel model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DefaultConfigurationModel>(modelData);

        string[] rangeSplit = Regex.Split(range, " - ");

        foreach (IdentifiBINConfiguration ibc in model.IdentifiBINConfigs)
        {
            if (ibc.LowerRange == rangeSplit[0] && ibc.UpperRange == rangeSplit[1])
            {
                model.IdentifiBINConfiguration = ibc;
                return Json(new { error = 0 });
            }
        }

        return Json(new { error = 1 });
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
The value "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]" is not of type "IdentifiMessenger.Implementations.Identifi.Object.IdentifiBINConfiguration" and cannot be used in this generic collection. Parameter name: value
```

And I don't know what that means at all. I know what the Dictionary is, but why can I not just deserialize this object? I followed other answers right here on SO and I don't understand why this isn't working.

Edit:
`Model` is quite literally my model, sent from my JS like this:

```
IdentifiConfig.SetBinConfig(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)), $('#BinRangesHidden').val());
```

And `range` is just a value from a `hidden`. I'm not posting back my model because I just need to modify one value and then have the page pull that modified value down later.

Comment: What is `model` and `range` in your function? Why are your not just posting back your model?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I made some edits.

Comment: `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` is the values of the initial model you rendered in the view so its pointless to post it back to a controller which already knows what it is. And what is the value of `$('#BinRangesHidden').val()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's not pointless because I am trying to modify the data of the model manually which cannot be done in the view. How is that pointless?

Comment: The message means that deserializer don't know how to convert your JSON to IdentifiBINConfiguration type. Could you show us your IdentifiBINConfiguration and DefaultConfigurationModel classes?

Comment: No where in your code do you modify the value of `model`! (or do you think that `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` reflects changes you make in the form?).

Comment: `model.IdentifiBINConfiguration = ibc;` in the foreach loop modifies a field within the model

Comment: That code that's on the server - not the client! All you are doing is sending a model to the view and then in your ajax function sending it all back again to the controller with exactly the same values (completely unchanged!)

Comment: Ok, how do I send it back to the view without reloading the page?  I can't let the page reload, but I need to modify a value in the model. Any ideas?

Comment: Impossible to understand what your actually trying to do here. Even the controller code does not make sense. You modify a property of an object in the controller but don't save it, so as soon as you return, its all disposed and lost anyway

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You still have to serialize your data.

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

Then in your controller, your object should auto-parse:

```
public ActionResult SetBinConfiguration(MyData data)
```

Alternatively, you can parse it manually:

```
public ActionResult SetBinConfiguration(string data)
{
    MyData resumeDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(data);
...
```

Comment: I did serialize my data : `var _model = JSON.stringify(model);`. And I need more than one parameter sent to my controller. I'm sorry, but it seems like you didn't read my question.

Comment: If you look at my question you'll see I'm already trying to deserialize my object. Please, read my question before answering.

Comment: You are manually manipulating your strings both before and after the post.  It is likely that your JSON is not being parsed correctly.  Can you share the output of your JSON.  Also, it is not clear what your trying to do.